# Batch logging using interpolation

Tags: batch-file, logging, stdout, stderr, error-logging

I don't remember where I got this code snippet from but it has come in handle but with one downfall -- it doesn't redirect stderr in time!

```
@echo off
set logit=^> _ 2^>^&1 ^&^& type _^&^&type _^>^>script.log^&^&DEL /q _

REM "just stdout output" will be printed to STDOUT and logged properly
echo just stdout output %logit%

REM ls with spit out an error message to STDERR and will NOT be logged
ls %logit%
```

The above code basically relies on the fact that logit will be expanded to do the following:

1. Send STDOUT to file called "_" while redirecting STDERR to STDOUT
2. Type out file "_" to the screen
3. Type out file "_" to the "script.log" file
4. Delete the "_" file

The problem is in the STDERR to STDOUT redirect. I know that 2>&1 should happen last on the command line. "&&" concatenates commands that previously would have to be on the separate lines. As such, it kind of makes sense to put 2>&1 before the first && occurrence. Yet, it doesn't work. Putting 2>&1 last also doesn't do anything:

```
set lotit==^> _ ^&^& type _^&^&type _^>^>script.log^&^&DEL /q _ 2^>^&1
```

However, breaking out the commands in the following way works as expected:

```
@echo off

REM "just stdout output" will be printed to STDOUT and logged properly
echo just stdout output > _ 2>&1
type _&&type _>>script.log&&DEL /q _

REM ls with spit out an error message to STDERR and will NOT be logged
ls > _ 2>&1
type _&&type _>>script.log&&DEL /q _
```

Does anyone know of a way I can make STDERR redirect into STDOUT using the original example with %logit% expansion?

Comment: you should remove the `DEL`. It might try to delete before the redirection is done. And it generates another write-access to disk. Instead just delete `_` once at the very end of your script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`&&` is an operator that executes the following command on a result of errorlevel zero.  A single `&` executes the next command normally.

With redirection the STDOUT is redirected first, and then the STDERR is redirected to STDOUT.
It looks like your code is doing that.

It's probable that the errorlevel is 1 or higher so the next commands don't run.
The solution there is to change all `&&` to `&` and in your code `^&^&` to `^&`